# How to create a single long variable ordered by and from multiple variables

Tags: r

So basically my data is set up as:

a=c(1,2,3);
b=c(4,5,6);
 and so on to
z=c(77,78,79);
x=cbind(a,b,...,z)

And I want to create a single column from these columns a through z so some variable alpha=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,...,78). That is, have all values for a, then after that all the values for b, then list all values for c, all the way through to z. Is there a way to do this quickly in R?

I've tried rbind, cbind, and a couple of the long/short transforms. It's one of those problems that seems like it should be simple but I keep getting matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c() command works too. For instance:

```
x <-1:5
y <-6:10
z <-11:15

data <-c(x,y,z)

data

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: JPP, thank you for your help. I have no idea how I never learned about the c() command. I've been using R for a while now too. Good news: it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:78, nrow = 3))
colnames(dat) <- letters
dat
  a b c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
1 1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46 49 52 55 58 61 64 67 70 73 76
2 2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68 71 74 77
3 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78  

alpha <- unlist(dat)
alpha
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3 e1 e2 e3 f1 f2 f3 g1 g2 g3 h1 h2 h3 i1 i2 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
i3 j1 j2 j3 k1 k2 k3 l1 l2 l3 m1 m2 m3 n1 n2 n3 o1 o2 o3 p1 p2 p3 q1 q2 q3 r1 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 
r2 r3 s1 s2 s3 t1 t2 t3 u1 u2 u3 v1 v2 v3 w1 w2 w3 x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 z1 z2 z3 
53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
```

Comment: For some reason, possibly because my actual set was different than the simple example above, your solution did not work. However, JPP's did below. Thank you for your answer. Any idea why unlist might return exactly what I put into it?

Comment: must be something to do with your `data.frame` structure. Try and add a small example of what it is like in your question, The output of `dput(head(myData))` should help us give an answer.